# JavaScript Capitalizing First Letter of a String

Tags: javascript, html

I have written the code within the HTML file and it doesn't work typing lower or console.log(lower) does not display anything.

However when I type the same code

```
const lower = 'this is a lowercase string'
const upper = lower.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lower.substring(1);
```

directly into the JS console it works perfectly fine.

Comment: need to see the HTML snippet

Comment: Maybe you need to show us how you are printing this into your HTML file?

Comment: How can we diagnose something we can’t see?

Comment: do you need a js or css solution for this one ?

Comment: Give some idea on what are you trying to do in the html???

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything within the HTML just print the results of const lower and upper to the console

Answer (score 1):

Here is script to help you.

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}
```

With this prototype, you can make first letter as Uppercase.

Comment: Also there is css solution
```
p:first-letter {
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Comment: You can use Regular Expression

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function () {
  return this.replace(/^./, function (match) {
    return match.toUpperCase();
  });
};
```

If you use any method, you can get proper result that you want.

Comment: instead of expanding on your answer in the comments, why not add this information to the answer itself?

Comment: it's just helpful additional answer so if anyone care about it, he or she will look at it. :)